# References for coordinate-free linear algebra books

Tags: linear-algebra, reference-request, book-recommendation

I'm looking for some (or one) good book(s) that teach linear algebra either purely coordinate-free or ones that present the standard bag-of-tools alongside coordinate-free alternatives or discussions. Thanks!

Comment: I very much enjoy "A Second Course in Linear Algebra" by Brown.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Stephen Roman's *Advanced Linear Algebra*. It's a gem.

You may also care to look at chapters 10-12 of Dummit and Foote's *Abstract Algebra*.

Comment: Thanks! These two sources are certainly along the lines of what I was looking for (and "A second course in linear algebra" is also very good).

Answer (score 1):

S. Winitzki, [Linear Algebra via Exterior Products](https://sites.google.com/site/winitzki/linalg) (free book, coordinate-free approach)